# Does sweating interfere to the muscle/weight gain?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, gym, muscle-gain, sweat

#### Details

I do train by **[5x5 program](https://stronglifts.com/5x5/)** to gain muscle and weight, 3 times in the gym per week, keeping my training sessions short: 30 - 45 min, each workout I wear very warm: t-shirt, hoodie, underpants and short pants (and it's in boiling summer) so it's not surprising that I'm very sweating while the training.

When I'm wearing warm I feel that training being better in terms of a better stretch of muscle, feeling the power/ability to do more reps by keeping muscle warm.

**Things that also should be considered:**

- I'm 23 years old
- weight: 66 kg / 145 lbs
- height: 185 cm / 72,8 inch
- during the training, I'm drinking the gainer

#### Questions

Does sweating interfere to the muscle/weight gain?

Can a workout of this kind somehow hurt the heart?

Comment: What's happening is that you're burning more fuel because your body has to keep itself cool (which is why you're sweating). If you want to gain weight, you need a caloric surplus. So if you have a hard time consuming enough calories then you might want to stop wearing all of these clothes in order to make your body burn less calories. If you don't have a problem consuming these extra calories, then you might aswell train like this is you prefer it.

Comment: @MJB you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, quit overthinking. Keep at it.

Consult a doctor, not an online forum about your heart health.

Comment: Yes it can, and these kinds of answers don't really help, if you want to give a comment like this put it in the comments please.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you're burning more fuel because your body has to keep itself cool (which is why you're sweating).

If you want to gain weight, you need a caloric surplus. So if you have a hard time consuming enough calories then you might want to stop wearing all of these clothes in order to make your body burn less calories. If you don't have a problem consuming these extra calories, then you might aswell train like this is you prefer it.